# How to use more shipping rates in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

do you know how can I show in my checkout more than one shipping cost?
When I try to do that the result is always a selection between the 2 rates, but I would like them to sum eachother.

Can someone help me?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

In Woocommerce a shopper can only select one shipping method. It would not make any sense for someone to be able to select more then one shipping method.

If you want to vary the shipping fee based on some order options, then you need to take a look at this extension for Woocommerce https://www.woothemes.com/products/table-rate-shipping/.

Comment: Hi @Scriptonomy, i need to do that because I need something like this: Shipping cost #1: 5$ Shipping cost #2: 10$

Total shipping costs: 15$. But I need both of them, that's my problem. In your opinion, how can I do? Thanks and regards